# charAt() for integers greater than 1?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that displays the `x` and `y` coordinates of any given point, reflected across the linear function `ax+b`. However, I get a runtime error which says that it's out of bounds. I know you can't invoke methods on primitive data types, but I have no idea how else to get it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReflectivePoint {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Scanner lol = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the linear function.");

        //That will be in the format ax+b
        String function = lol.nextLine();
        Scanner lol2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the point.");

        //That will be in the format a,b
        String point = lol2.nextLine();
        int a = point.charAt(1);
        int b = point.charAt(3);
        int m = function.charAt(1);
        int c = function.charAt(4);
        int x1 = (2 / (m + 1 / m)) * (c + b - a / m) - a;
        int y1 = (-1/m) * x1 + a / m + b;
        System.out.println(x1+", "+y1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String.charAt(0)` indicates first char.

Comment: There's no such thing as a compiler error saying an index is out of bounds.

Comment: You don't need to create a new scanner for each line you try to read; use the same one.

Comment: it's a run-time exception, not a compile-time exception..that's what @Hugo is giving you grief about..

Comment: I gues you are getting a runtime exception -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html after you started the programm and entered some input text ... see the stacktrace to find out on witch line ... from what i see ist the line `int b = point.charAt(3);` the first candidate for such an error since `a` has the index 0, `,` has the index `1` and `b` the index `2`, so for the index `3` there is nothing the get -> out of range `[0-2]` . to fix that see the comment of AVD, Index count starts at 0 !

Comment: Note that, if the focus of this exercise is the maths, it's probably better to get the inputs from the command line arguments than reading from System.in -- just use the Strings in args[]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are getting a String of length 3, eg "1,2".

charAt(3) will try and return the 4th char of the String which doesn't exists so it throws an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

The index out of bounds error means "You have asked me for the 4th character of this string, but the string has fewer than 4 characters."

Note that (like most computer language indexes), the first character is 0. charAt("hello",1) == 'e'

You should check the length of the string before calling charAt(). Or, catch the exception and handle it.

charAt() probably isn't the best choice for your program, because it will only currently handle single-digits. Try String.split() to split the String on the comma.

Also, at the moment it's using the ASCII value of the character. That is (if you fixed the indexes) "a,b" would result in you doing your maths with m=97 and c=98. I guess that's not what you want. Find out about Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int a = point.charAt(0);
```

*provided* that that `point` is not empty.

Ideally you should perform a pre-use length check on the input String.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the out of bounds issue, which others have pointed out is you need to start at `charAt(0)` because the number is an offset into the char array (string), not getting the `n`th element.

You also need to subtract '0' to convert to an integer.

```
string point = "4";
int a = point.charAt(0);
//a=52 //not what you wanted

string point = "4";
int a = point.charAt(0) - '0';
//a=4 //this is what you wanted
```